# Custom renderer DatePicker CountDownTimer does not datechanged value in Xamarin forms

Tags: c#, xamarin, xamarin.forms, xamarin.ios

So i am trying to create a timepicker where the user is able to select a number from where a count still start from. So i found out you could do a datepicker renderer for this and use something called `CountDownTimer`, fair enough, i implemented this and it looks good when i try to use!

However now when i try to get out the value once a change is made it does not trigger any of the events and if it does, it does not return the intended value but an actual date instead. Ive tried multiple ways as you will see.

```
public class DatePickerRenderer_iOS : DatePickerRenderer
{
    protected override void OnElementChanged(ElementChangedEventArgs<DatePicker> e)
    {
        base.OnElementChanged(e);

        if (e.NewElement != null)
        {
            var picker = Control.InputView as UIDatePicker;
            if (picker != null)
            {
                picker.Mode = UIDatePickerMode.CountDownTimer;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

How i use it (`pickerTime` is my picker name in XAML):

```
    void PickerTime_Unfocused(object sender, FocusEventArgs e)
    {
        System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine(pickerTime.Date); // Triggers but returns a datetime, not the actualy selected hour + minute.
    }


    void PickerTime_PropertyChanging(object sender, PropertyChangingEventArgs e)
    {
        System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine(pickerTime.Date);
    }


    private void DatePicker_DateSelected(object sender, DateChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine(e.NewDate);
    }
```

Any ideas on how this could be adjusted so that i get the updated value directly when the datepicker is changed? And how would i get the correct value (not a date, but a minute + hour value, just like the CountDownTimer implementation is for)?

Answer (score 0):

The base `DatePicker`'s `Date` property is naturally of the `DateTime` type. So in order to get the exact minute and hour out of DateTime;

```
var date = pickerTime.Date;
string hourMinute = date.ToString("HH:mm");
```

Comment: Thanks :) That would solve the first issue, but how would i be able to get datepicker changed event to trigger? Right now i can only get an event of trigger when the datepicker is "unfocused", but i would rather have it while people are scrolling in it

Comment: Is your `DatePicker_DateSelected` event handler correctly wired to your xaml control? Have you tried debugging that handler while using the control? I've noticed with iOS the picker family can be a little wonky with a weird delay in selecting items, whether thats in a picker, datepicker or timepicker.

Comment: No i hook it up in my constructor event like this: 
`pickerTime.DateSelected += DatePicker_DateSelected;`

Comment: Either way works, I'm kind of confused on what your goal is and what it's currently doing... is `e.NewDate` in your event handler not returning the `DateTime` that your user selected?

Comment: DatePicker_DateSelected event is not getting fired for me once iam scroll through the picker